# error apache configuration error: couldn't perform authentication. AuthType not set!: / on centos 6

Tags: django, apache, centos

I want in CentOS 6
Using Apache. I set up Django 1.8.
Apache configuration've put as follows.

```
 WSGIScriptAlias /io /home/ahmad/io/io/wsgi.py
 WSGIPythonPath /home/ahmad/io/:/home/ahmad/io/io/:/home/ahmad/myprojectenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages

 Alias /static/ "/home/ahmad/io/static/"
 DocumentRoot /home/ahmad/io/

 <Directory /home/ahmad/io/io/>
      <Files wsgi.py>
          Require all granted
      </Files>
 </Directory>
```

But the Internal Server Error error at run time.
And writes the following error log.

```
configuration error:  couldn't perform authentication. AuthType not set!: /io
```

please guide me.

Answer (score 11):

If your apache version is below 2.4 change

> "Require all granted"

to

> "Allow from all"